# Single subject independency of repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures

In part of an experimental trial (n=1), I asked the participant to answer a specific questionnaire (continuous response variable) under the influence of 4 different dosages (dosage 1, 2, 3 and 4) of a same substance. This task was repeated (after a certain washout interval) under 3 different conditions.

Can I consider the 3 conditions under which my subject undertakes the task as independent (I would say yes) and I am allowed to undertake statistical analysis for example for each of the condition independently (for example, perform an ANOVA for each of the conditions)?

I am aware that I won't be able to generalise my results but I am just looking for the best method to present my results (in addition to presenting some graphs)

I would be very thankful for any hint or advice!